# CasperJS form not submitting in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css-selectors, casperjs

I am going to use CasperJS for for testing, form submitting and UI testing, and I am new to CasperJS and AngularJS. While doing testing with CasperJS my form is not submitting, but it gives errors, that is, form not found.

**Here is my form**

```
<form role="form" name="login-form">
    <div class="list list-inset col-sm-6 well col-md-offset-3 shadowBox">
         <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label ">
          <span class="input-label">Email</span>
         </label>
        <div class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
          <input class="form-control" name="emailId" type="email" ng-model="loginData.email" placeholder="Email" required>
        </div>
        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
          <span class="input-label">Password</span>
        </label>
        <div class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
          <input class="form-control" name="passwordId" type="password" ng-model="loginData.password" placeholder="Password" required>
        </div>
        <div class="message-box  alert-danger text-center" role="alert" ng-hide="!message.length">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
              <span data-ng-bind="message"></span>
         </div>
         <div class="item" ng-show="{{applicationType}}">
              <hr/>
              <button class="button button-positive pull-right btn btn-primary"   ng-click="doLogin(loginData)" id="success">Log in</button>
              <a ng-click="goToForgotPassword()" class="button button-clear button-positive">Forgot password?</a>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        <label class="item" ng-hide="{{applicationType}}">
            <button class="button button-positive"   ng-click="doLogin(loginData)" id="success">Log in</button>
             <a ng-click="goToForgotPassword()" class="button button-clear button-positive">Forgot password?</a></div>
        </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Here is my CasperJS code**

```
casper.start('http://localhost:3000/#/login', function() {
    this.fillSelectors('form#login-form', {
        'emailId':    'test@gmail.com',
        'passwordId':    'test123'
    }, false);
});

casper.then(function() {
    this.evaluateOrDie(function() {
        return /message sent/.test(document.body.innerText);
    }, 'sending message failed');
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.echo(this.getHTML());
    this.echo('message sent').exit();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is wrong. You mean to use `form[name="login-form"]`. You initial selector is actually equal to `form[id="login-form"]`, because `#` is the id selector.

Note that you use the `fillSelectors` function, so you need to use actual selectors to find the fields.

Since this is angularjs, you might also need to wait for the form to appear.

Full code:

```
casper.start('http://localhost:3000/#/login');

casper.waitForSelector('form[name="login-form"] input[name="emailId"]', function() {
    this.fillSelectors('form[name="login-form"]', {
        'input[name="emailId"]':    'test@gmail.com',
        'input[name="passwordId"]':    'test123'
    }, false);
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.echo(this.getHTML());
    this.echo('message sent').exit();
});
```

---

Also note that the step which contains `evaluateOrDie` isn't doing anything useful. You don't use the argument that you pass into the page context and you don't use the value that you return from the page context.

Comment: Thanks, friends i  am new to casperjs if i give wrong password and email that is not registered then what happen in above form is casperjs check that value in database, and also let me know after successfully login then open profile if not then gives error. plz suggest

Comment: I don't understand what your issue is now. You might want to ask a new question and describe in detail what the problem is. Please note that linking to your source code won't help. You have to include all information to reproduce/answer your question in the question body itself

Comment: If ' 'input[name="emailId"]':    'blank ', ' so that test case is pass or fails

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to determine in the script if the login was successful. Generally this is done by looking at the success and fail page and looking for an element which is one of them but not the other. You then check in your script whether the element is there with `casper.exists(selector)` and continue your script based on this information.